# How to change page header depending session on asp.net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, session

I'm working in a VisualStudio project but I need help.
I have a database with the user information which includes a value to obtain the role. Depending that value, I need to change the page header to show/hide links and options, but I don't know how to make it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to implement what you want

```
void privilege ()
        {
            if(Session["role"].ToString() !="Admin")
            {
               //do somethings
            }
            else
            {
               //do other things 
            }
        }
```